# How not to show up in the “stalker feed” in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

There's this thing just above the box where you can select a friend to chat with in Facebook. I don't really know what its called so I just called it stalker feed (please also enlighten me what its called).

Can I control whether I show up or not on that box when I liked something or commented to a post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s called *[ticker](http://www.facebook.com/help/ticker)* and it shows you the things you can already see on Facebook, but in real time.

And no, you can’t control it directly.

> **[Who can see stories about my comments and likes in ticker?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=171783462899295#Who-can-see-stories-about-my-comments-and-likes-in-ticker?)**
>
> To control stories about your commenting activity in ticker and news feed, always check who can see the privacy of the posts you're commenting on. Learn more about sharing privacy. If you aren't comfortable with who can see the post, please don't comment on it or like it. If you do, a story about your activity will be eligible to appear on Facebook, including on your timeline (profile), in news feed and in ticker.

Comment: so I can't opt out of it as well?

Comment: No, you can’t opt out.